# Common cache for turducken pattern - How to share data between GWT modules

Tags: caching, serialization, gwt, web-applications

I've splitted a GWT application via the [turducken pattern](https://de.slideshare.net/RobertKeane1/turducken-divide-and-conquer-large-gwt-apps-with-multiple-teams). Now I want to share some data on the client side that are used by both modules to prevent multiple service calls for redundant data. Both modules of course exist in the same DOM.

As both modules are built independently I'm afraid that I cannot just make the Gwt object accessible via a JSNI function or so (because of different obfuscation).

I've tried an appoach via AutoBeans serialization but it's quite slow for larger objects and requires a lot of boilerplate code. Is there another idea how to easily share data on client side between GWT modules in the same DOM?

Comment: Did you try to use `Window.postMessage` using Jsinterop with json data.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: The problem more the serialization itself. As I said it is very costly with AutoBeans (in both code writing and performance).

Comment: Did you try as serializing to JSON using jackson-apt, should be fast, https://github.com/DominoKit/gwt-jackson-apt

Comment: Although it is super limited, JsInterop DTO strategy (https://github.com/intendia-oss/autorest/wiki/JsInterop-DTO-strategy) is pretty useful in these cases, here (https://github.com/ibaca/rxcanvas-gwt/blob/master/src/main/java/rxcanvas/client/RxCanvas.java#L189) I use it to communicate between different GWT clients. You can store these DTOs in local persistent storage, using it as a cache.